# ArrayList from object and specific name for the objects

Tags: java, arraylist

Im learning to make a game, and im nearly done with the main part, but cant get one thing working. 
I need to generate some fields from `Field.java`
The Code from Field.java is the following

```
package matedor;

class Field{
    private String name;
    private int number;

    public Field (String fieldname, int fieldnumber){
        this.name = fieldname;
        this.number= fieldnumber;
    }

    public String getFieldname(){
        return name;
    }
    public int getFieldnumber(){
        return number;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return number+name;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj){
       Field field = (Field) obj;
        return (number == field.number && name.equals(field.name));
    }
}
```

In my main i need to generate the following which is not editable:

```
fieldname1, fieldname2.....to fieldname40
```

I know i have to do it with an ArrayList, and i want to create 40 instances of the field, so i have from fieldname1 to fieldname40. 
How do i do that?

In my main i have tried to do the following, but i get the null statement

```
 Field[] felterISpil=new Field[40];
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(felterISpil));
```

Output:

```
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

Comment: please keep your bracket style consistent and format your code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to initialize .you are getting null because default value of objects are `null`.you have `declare` but haven't `initialize` yet.

you need to pass `String fieldname,` `int fieldnumber` to the constructor when you initialize .your constructor have 2 parameters `String fieldname, int fieldnumber`

```
public Field (String fieldname, int fieldnumber)
```

that's why you need to pass a `String and int`

```
felterISpil[0]=new Field("fieldname",1);
felterISpil[1]=new Field("fieldname2",2);
```

you should pass values you want to the constructor .how ever if you want to test it without initializing one by one following code will initialize all element of your field array

```
for(int i=0;i<felterISpil.length;i++){
   felterISpil[i]=new Field("fieldname",1);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(felterISpil));
```

output is not null anymore

Comment: i get an error when i do that.
Create constructor field() in Matedor.Field

Comment: @user1098185 you should pass String fieldname, int fieldnumber to the constructor

Comment: Doesnt give any sense to me, what you are trying to say :)
I want to create it from the Class Field

Comment: @user1098185 you have declare 2 variable of your class private String name;
private int number; so you have initialize them in the constructor .when you create a object of your class you need to pass a String.this is your constructor which requred String and int  value and int value to it.
public Field (String fieldname, int fieldnumber);

Comment: Can you try to give me an example?

Comment: Thanks! that was greatfull.

Comment: How can i change the first string in the arraylist to ex. "Start"

Comment: @user1098185 felterISpil[0]=new Field("Start",1);

Comment: I need to remove the 1 from the "start"

Comment: @user1098185 then you have change your constructor to 

*public Field (String fieldname)*

Answer (score 1):

First of all keep in mind that you are creating constructor of class Field. So in main() after you have created a Array of field class by doing this Field felterISpil[] = new Field[40]; then before call any method of Field class you need to create object of it by doing this felterSpil[index] = new Field(FieldName, FieldNumber);
As u specify in ur constructor this way syntax actual it will.
felterSpil[0] = new Field(Field1, 1);
And then you can call any method u will get proper value

Comment: My suggestion may be looks so improper i have Written it through my mobile but its upto the point n cover what u need ok. Hope it helps u

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of each `Field`
Try the following:

```
List fields = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 1; i <= 40; i++){
    fields.add(new Field("Field"+i, i));
}
```